# Using AngularJS and KendoGrid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am learning AngularJS and trying to use the Telerik KendoGrid in a directive. I have a directive that that will access a service and get some data. Part of the data will be used to populate an observable array in the directive. The html that is associated to that directive has another directive within it that will create a kendoGrid that should be editable. When I click on the update button I get an undefined error and the grid data disappears. 
I define my array as follows:

```
$scope.currentData.event.submissionDates = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([
        ]);
```

and on success of call push the data into the array.
the grid is called as follows in the html:

```
<submission-grid class="grid-16" event="currentData.event" ng-show="currentData.event.eventID"></submission-grid>
```

This directive calls the following html file:

```
<div kendo-grid="grid" 
 k-columns="gridColumns"
 k-selectable="true"
 k-on-change="selected = data"
 k-options ="mainGridOptions "
 k-editable ="{'mode': 'inline', 'update': 'true'}"
```

and the backing js is:

```
(function () {

angular.module('app.submissionGrid', [])

.directive('submissionGrid', function () {

    var ctrlr = function ($scope) {

        $scope.gridColumns = [{
                field: "SubmissionDueDate",
                title: "Due Date",
                format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
                width: "100px"
            }, {
                field: "Source",
                title: "Agency",
                width: "100px"
            }, {
                field: "SubmissionFiledDate",
                title: "Filed Date",
                format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
                width: "100px"
            }, {
                field: "SeverityCategory",
                title: "Severity Category",
                width: "100px"
            }, { command: ["edit", ], title: " ", width: "200px" }
        ];


        $scope.mainGridOptions = {
            dataSource: {
                data: $scope.event.submissionDates,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "ReportId",
                        fields: {
                            SubmissionDueDate: { type: "string" },
                            Source: { type: "string" },
                            SubmissionFiledDate: { type: "string" },
                            SeverityCategory: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'App/Event/SubmissionGrid/submissionGrid.html',
        controller: ctrlr,
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
            event: '='
        }
    };
})
```

})();

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Message and stack trace?